# Multiplying two numbers in JavaScript with only addition and subtraction (no logs)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I am trying multiply two numbers together using only addition/subtraction (for practice with algorithms as I am new to JavaScript).  I got it to work with logs but I want to try with only addition/subtraction. Is there any way to do this without a subroutine- the addY function that I have at the bottom? Would also be great to know how to do this without a for loop!

```
var multiply = function(x, y) {

  //add y x times
  // function log10(val) {
  //     return Math.log(val) / Math.LN10;
  // }
  // return Math.round(Math.pow(10, (log10(x) + log10(y))))
  if(x === 1){
    return y;
  }
  if(y === 1){
    return x;
  }
  if (x === 0 || y === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  //if one is negative
  if(x < 0 ^ y <0){
    return -multiply(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y))
  }
  //if both are negative
  if(x<0 && y<0){
    return multiply(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));
  }

  //subroutine:
  var addY = function (x, y){
    var total= 0;
    for(var i = 0; i<x; i++){
        total += y;
    }
    return total;
  }

  return addY(x, y);
};

console.log(multiply(55, -2)) 
// ---> returns -110 woohoo!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, multiplication is easy if you use a loop. The only caveat is that you need to get your variables to be positive before you can add them up using a loop, or you'll introduce risk of an infinite loop.

One easy approach is to use recursion to switch the signs around whenever a negative number is encountered.

```
function multiply(a, b) {
    if (a < 0) {
      return -(multiply(-a, b))
    } else if (b < 0) {
      return -(multiply(a, -b))
    } else {
      var total = 0;
      // math to calculate product goes here
      return total;
    }
  }
```

Although maybe that counts as cheating, since `-a` is mathematically equivalent to `a * -1`.

***Edit:*** Jiggszon suggests performing `0-a` instead of `-a` to avoid cheating.

In any case, here's an implementation so you can see it in action:

```js
(function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("x");
  var y = document.getElementById("y");
  var z = document.getElementById("output");
  document.getElementById("btnCalc").addEventListener("click", function() {
    z.innerHTML = multiply(+x.value, +y.value);
  });


  function multiply(a, b) {
    if (a < 0) {
      return 0-(multiply(0-a, b))
    } else if (b < 0) {
      return 0-(multiply(a, 0-b))
    } else {
      var smallerNumber;
      var biggerNumber;
      if (a <= b) {
        smallerNumber = a;
        biggerNumber = b;
      } else {
        smallerNumber = b;
        biggerNumber = a;
      }
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < smallerNumber; i++) {
        total += biggerNumber;
      }
      return total;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnCalc" value="Calculate" />
<input type="text" value=100 id="x" />x
<input type="text" value=3 id="y" />=
<span id="output"></span>
```

The only other thing worth pointing out in the above code is that it checks to see if one of the variables is smaller than the other before doing the loop. That way it iterates as few times as possible!

Comment: To avoid cheating would 0-a do?

Comment: @jiggzson Good thinking!

Answer (score 2):

```js
function multiply(x, y) {
    var product = 0, sign = x > 0 ? 1 : -1, y = x > 0 ? y : 0 - y;
    if (x && y) do product += y; while (x -= sign);
    return product;
}

alert(multiply( 5,  7));
alert(multiply(-5,  7));
alert(multiply( 5, -7));
alert(multiply(-5, -7));
alert(multiply( 0,  7));
alert(multiply( 5,  0));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to multiply, you can just make a loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i<y; i++){
    x +=x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this using a `while` loop instead of a `for`, but I think you'll always need some kind of iteration.

```
var multiply = function(x, y) {
    if (y === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    var minus = y < 0;

    if (minus) {
        y = -y;
    }

    var total = x;

    while (y > 1) {
        total += x;
        y--;
    }

    return minus ? -total : total;
}
```